# Delegate issue in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5

I want to call multiple delegate simultaneously in my iphone application.is it possible?if possible please provide me guideline.Thanks

Comment: please give detail that exactly what u want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not possible to call/assign multiple delegates to a single protocol. You can always do it with notifications. The delegate classes in your context should listen for the notification.